# What to look for when buying muffin tins?

Tags: baking, equipment

Because honestly, I wouldn't be nearly so in love with my dutch oven without the advice I got on this site. And I really believe in getting one good lifetime tool, rather than a bunch of cheap ones.

I'm kind of creeped out by [Teflon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene), and will probably skip coatings. I've read here that baking with the silicone cup-type things isn't necessarily any better than a metal pan.

Are there any metal types or finishes that give better baking results?

Comment: Muffins are very forgiving to pan material, you don't have to select it by heating properties. Just go for whatever is easiest to handle. I love my silicone cups, they are low maintenance and function perfectly.

Comment: @rumtscho people cook more than just muffins in these pans. Egg-based dishes for brunch, mini-meat loaves, cup cakes, etc. I'm facing the same dilemma as the OP. What metal (aluminum, stainless, cast iron)? Dark or shiny? Thick/heavy or thin? Coating or no coating?

Answer (score 9):

In general, the darker the color of the metal of the muffin tin the more it will brown its contents.  You also want to look for a thick, durable metal as this will aid in even cooking.  Finally, look for a tin with large, wide handles; the last thing you want to be doing is sticking your thumbs into a muffin when trying to insert/remove the tin from the oven!  Most muffin tins these days are non-stick, so it may be hard to find one that is not.  With that said, non-stick technology has advanced a bit since the Teflon-only days.  For example, many modern non-stick pans/tins instead use other metals and ceramics that are not known to be harmful.  Furthermore, some modern muffin tins are marketed as "metal-safe", meaning that one can use a metal utensil on them (*e.g.*, to extract the muffins from the tin) without damaging the non-stick coating.  Finally, muffin tins will likely never be heated to the temperatures at which the "dangerous" non-stick coatings release harmful gasses.

Comment: Ceramics? That perks my ears. I'll have to read into that and "metal safe" - thanks for the info, and useful terms to research.

Comment: Please explain science behind "the darker the color of the metal of the muffin tin the more it will brown its contents" in relation to being in a domestic oven?

Comment: @TFD: I'm not sure about the science, but that's what [Cooks Illustrated](http://www.cooksillustrated.com/) concluded as a result of their "experiments".

Comment: @TFD darker materials absorb infrared light better than shiny. So a dark pan will be able to transfer more heat to muffins than a shiny pan, thus resulting in more browning. Many cookie recipes have 2 oven temperatures, for light vs dark cookie sheets.

Comment: @mpoisot infrared light in domestic oven? Mostly hot air

Comment: @TFD toasting and broiling (esp with the oven door open) cook almost exclusively via infrared. If the calrods are glowing red-hot, they are radiating infrared heat onto your food. When baking infrared is less prominent, but the walls of the oven and calrods still shine infrared light onto your food. A dark pan will absorb more of this heat and pump it into the food than a shiny pan.

Answer (score 2):

I've had very good results with this pan:

http://www.centralrestaurant.com/Large-Crown-Muffin-Pan---12-Cup-Capacity-c78p14727.html

It's made from aluminized steel and in our experience has a few things going for it:

- It's very heavy and holds its temperature well - haven't had uneven cooking that occurs in some older thin muffin pans we have.
- It doesn't have the dark metallic finish that can sometimes cause things to brown faster than you might like.
- It makes 20 nice sized muffins, so depending on your recipe, you may be able to get the full batch cooked in one shot and with one pan
- It includes a recess at the top of each muffin so you get the nice looking muffin top that everyone loves - because awesome muffins are the whole point anyway, right?